# D7 - when I change a display suite display mode, shouldn't views using that display mode also change?

Tags: 7, views, users, display-suite

I made a change to a display suite display mode, hoping that it would change a view that uses that display mode.  It did work while logged in, but as soon as I logged out it didn't work.  Yep, I did flush cache, multiple times.

Comment: Doesn't sound right; it should work properly. I suggest posting more details about your setup/configuration.

Comment: Does role anynomous have access right to DS, views and to the mode of DS?